# How do I keep my Facebook friends list and befriending notifications to myself?

Tags: facebook, privacy

I don’t want anyone to either see my friends list or to be notified of who I become friend with. I only want those two pieces of information limited to me. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prevent people from viewing your Friend List by following these steps:

- Go to *Account* → *Privacy Settings*
- In the **Connecting on Facebook** section click **View Settings**
- On the **See your Friend List** click the box to the right hand side and select **Customize**
- In the drop down box next to **These people** select **Only Me**
- Click **Save Setting**

I don't think it is possible to prevent the notification being posted to your wall though.

---

To hide your friends list under *Timeline*:

1. Go to you Timeline
2. Click on your friends list in the upper box
3. In the friends list window, click on **Edit** in the upper-right side
4. In the drop-down menu, click on the icon in the upper-right corner
5. In the menu that appears, choose **Only Me**
   [image]

Comment: You can chase it by deleting it off your wall as fall back method

Comment: @Eight - Yes, deleting the "are now friends" post on your wall, isn't ideal but it seems to be the only option at present.

Comment: Actually the friend list privacy setting applies to the friend stories in the recent activity as well.  So there is no need to delete them unless you don't even want to see them yourself.

Comment: @Eight Days of Malaise: just tested, it does not always work. Deleted friending is still visible 5 minutes from another friend's account (not a browser cache issue).

Comment: Is there an updated version of this? I think FB has changed their privacy options already.. I can't seem to find this under Privacy Settings.